# System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I develop in C# an site that on my computer works on all 3 browsers(FireFox, IE and Chrome).
    On other computer works on IE but on FireFox received following error:

```
"Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
English is an invalid culture identifier.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not  supported.
Parameter name: name
English is an invalid culture identifier.

Source Error:
Line 29:         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(langValue))
Line 30:         {
Line 31:             UICulture = langValue;
Line 32:             //Culture = langValue;
Line 33: "
```

I received same error on other computer on IE and Chrome but not on FireFox.
All browsers are updated to the newest  versions and are on Windows 7.
Can anyone give me a hint or a solution for this problem, please?
Thanks

Comment: where does the value of `langValue` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to do this:

Go to the Debug menu -> Exceptions... and check that everything is unchecked for the Exception list.

Also try to delete all the files from the ASP.NET temporary folders present at the below location:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Answer (score 1):

English is not an identifier. Try with "en" or "en-US"